# Error in SQL Query regarding inverted commas

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I am running following query in php :

```
$link = $_GET['link'];
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT sub_category FROM phonebook ORDER BY sub_category WHERE category = '$link' "; 
echo $query;
$sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

And it is giving following error:

> SELECT DISTINCT sub_category FROM phonebook ORDER BY sub_category WHERE category = 'Administration' You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE category = 'Administration'' at line 1

I am not able to understand what is the error in the inverted commas if any?

Comment: put ORDER BY sub_category at the end of the query

Comment: This is open to SQL injections.

Comment: Write `ORDER BY sub_category ` after WHERE condition

Comment: Olso strart using mysqli_* methods not mysql_*.

Comment: put order by at the end of your query . Like this $query = "SELECT DISTINCT sub_category FROM phonebook  WHERE category = '$link' ORDER BY sub_category".  and start using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Now it is giving following error : Unknown column 'sub_category' in 'field list'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT sub_category FROM phonebook ORDER BY sub_category WHERE category = '$link' ";
```

Into

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT sub_category FROM phonebook WHERE category = '".$link."' ORDER BY sub_category ";
```

You made the mistake "sub_caregory":

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT sub_caregory FROM phonebook WHERE category = '".$link."' ORDER BY sub_caregory ";
```

Comment: Now it is giving following error :  Unknown column 'sub_category' in 'field list'

Comment: than you must check your database table `phonebook` for the right column name, because `sub_category` is incorrect.

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri Could you please provide the "field names" of "table - phonebook"?

Comment: 1      id Primary int(11)   AUTO_INCREMENT 
 2 category varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci  
 3 sub_caregory varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci
 4 first_name varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci
 5 last_name varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci
 6 phone_no varchar(100) utf8_general_ci
 7 email_id varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci  
 8 designation varchar(100) utf8_general_ci
 9 office_add text latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri : use this query $query = "SELECT DISTINCT sub_caregory FROM phonebook WHERE category = '".$link."' ORDER BY sub_caregory ";

Comment: there is a column named sub_category in my phonebook table

Comment: No. you made the mistaken sub_category to sub_caregory save your table

Comment: thanks , my column name was wrongly named. Corrected it now.

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY should be after where close 
you cannot do

```
SELECT 
FROM 
OREDER BY
WHERE
```

the ORDER IS

```
SELECT 
FROM 
WHERE 
GROUP BY 
HAVING 
ORDER BY
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below:
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT sub_category FROM phonebook WHERE category = '".$link."' ORDER BY sub_category";
To check complete select statement you can view here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html